# How to set all tables and all views isolation level to read uncommited?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Currently, we have a lot of background services running. These services are inserting/updating bulk amount of data to the server. This is why our SELECT queries are blocking. So, for temporary I need to make all all tables and all views isolation level to read uncommitted. Is it possible?

Comment: Why no use snapshot isolation to get rid of that locking behaviour.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, snapshot takes more space then dirty read

Comment: There is no way of doing this. The isolation level is set by the client connections. If you use RCSI then read committed will automatically use SI rather than pessimistic locking but may well hammer your `tempdb` for version store if you have loads of concurrent bulk modifications.

Comment: @MartinSmith, then what will be quick(temporary) solutions of my blocks.

Comment: Is the version store used for inserts? I don't think it must be because there is no previous version. Bulk inserts therefore do not stress tempdb through snapshot versions. You should use snapshot isolation.

Comment: @usr, the background process insert/update/delete a huge amount of records? Should I use snapshot?

Comment: @user960567 maybe. I have never seen the tempdb usage be a problem and never heard anyone say that he has. On the other hand it makes your rows 14 bytes bigger. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverstorageengine/archive/2008/03/30/overhead-of-row-versioning.aspx If you can tolerate that your blocking problems go away just like that.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would like to tell you, reading uncommited data is nothing but Dirty Read.
for eg, of you are working with AdventureWorks Database, then you just fire this query

use AdventureWorks
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITED.

This will help you to view all the records created / updated by some transaction but not yet commited.
By default, in SQL Server, Transaction Isolation Level is set to READ COMMITED.
so untill there is exclusive lock locked by some query, other transaction is not able to view the data of other transaction which is in uncommited state.

Feel free to reply about the result.

Kind Regards, 
Ashay (India)

Answer (score -1):

in your select query use hint NoLock

```
select * from userTbl with(NOLOCK)
```

Comment: I need database wide option

Comment: This is bad advice because NOLOCK has certain negative consequence. It can't be recommended generally. If it was always good, it would be always on.

Comment: @usr Please read the question carefully. I have answered the question accordingly.NoLock is one of the way to read without any blocking and uncommited rows.And this was asked in the question. Read the question answer carefully before voting up or down.

Comment: Even from that standpoint this is not the answer: he wants *all* tables to be read uncommitted temporarily. That would be done through the isolation level setting.